# Complexity $log(p_{n}\#)$

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-complexity, primorial

Is $log(p_{n}\#)$ a polynomial complexity (we count complexity after $n$)?

$p_{n}\#$ is primorial.

Could anyone prove it (if possible)?

Comment: do you know the Chebyshev functions? $log(p_n\#)$ is a way of writing the expression of the first Chebyshev function. This might help, as per the Wikipedia: "the primorial $x\#$ is asymptotically equal to $e^{(1 + o(1))x}$, where "$o$" is the little-$o$ notation and together with the prime number theorem establishes the asymptotic behavior of $p_n\#$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Relation_to_primorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln \prod \limits_{k=1}^{n} p_k  = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln p_k $

$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln p_k = \theta(p_n) $ By definition (Read Chebyshev Theta function).

By the PNT $|\theta(p_n)-p_n| \leq \frac{p_n}{\ln p_n} $

And $ n \ln n < p_n <2 n \ln n$ using these one concludes that its $O(n \ln n)$ complexity.